# Arrange long Href name

Tags: html, css, href

Good day,
I have created 3 href links. However the name for the href are very long. How can i rearrange them so that they appear to be in three columns? I tried using /br but it makes my link vertical. I need them to be horizontal. For example,

Sales

Weekly assesment

on sales generated

directly from NOVA.

Followed by the othe two links beside it.This is in the html:

```
<div class="bbar">
            <a href="sales.html">Sales - Weekly assessment on sales generated directly from NOVA.&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="cust.html">Customer Service Charter - Weekly assessment on how we serve our customers.&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="collection.html">Collection - Weekly assessment on collection.</a>
        </div>
```

and this is in the .css

```
div.bbar
{
bottom : 15%;
left : 5%;
right : 5%;
color : black;
font-family : calibri;
font-size : 16px;
text-align : center;
padding : 5px;
position : absolute;
}
```

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle for that

Comment: Here, I put your code in a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/NJmnz/1/

Now, can you explain what you mean by ”appear to be in three columns”?

Comment: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/

Comment: @Quentin, do you know how to code for responsive grid? i did the rest and its perfect, just the column width. Thus with the responsive grid it should resize accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `a`'s `inline-block`, and give them a width to make them appear next to each others: 
http://jsfiddle.net/NJmnz/5/

```
.bbar a {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 32%;
  vertical-align: top; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution -- 3 columns.  on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Bz92/7/)

### HTML

```
<div class="bbar">
            <a href="sales.html">Sales - Weekly assessment on sales generated directly from NOVA.&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="cust.html">Customer Service Charter - Weekly assessment on how we serve our customers.&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="collection.html">Collection - Weekly assessment on collection.</a>
        </div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

### CSS

```
div.bbar
{
bottom : 15%;
left : 5%;
right : 5%;
color : black;
font-family : calibri;
font-size : 16px;
text-align : center;
padding : 5px;
position : absolute;
}

div.bbar a {
  width: 32%;
  display: inline;
  text-align: justify;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
.bbar  a {
    float: left;
}
```